# Validation before implicit cast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, casting, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a model with an attribute that should be only numerical. So I added

```
validate :attribute, numericality: true
```

If I try to create a new object of that type in the console giving a string "abc" to that attribute, I got it converted in 0 before even validating it. So I don't have any error.

Is it possible to avoid the implicit cast at all or at least validating before it?
I tried also adding :on:create at the previous validation, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  before_validation(on: :create) do
      if attribute_present?("number")
        ##process ahead with self.number
      end
  end
```

Comment: Hi @user3702916,i have updated my answer,GIVE IT A TRY

Comment: this is what I am trying:

  before_validation(on: :create) do  
    if not self.attribute.is_a? Numeric  
      self.errors[:attribute] << "attribute must be a number"  
    end  
  end  

it is still not working